# is it possible for delete file without new file instance in Java?

Tags: java

I have a simple function used for file delete,

it will check the file size,

if small than a specific value, delete the file

however, this function will be called thousand times

and every time it will new file instance,

i think it will be expensive on file object creation issue,

is there any other way to fix this issue?

```
public void checkFile(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath); //this is expensive
    if (file.length() < 500) {
         file.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not hesitate for object creation and performance in Java. Java is made for this and they work the last 16 years to make it even better ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect on the performance of the `new File()` compared to checking the file size on the disk is miniscule. Don't worry about it.

If you really really think that it will make a difference, *measure it* and then optimise it.

Comment: +1: Creating a new File object takes up to 100 ns, deleting a file takes around 10 ms on a hard disk. i.e. its about 100,000x slower.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO "thinking" isn't good enough; have you really identified that `File` object creation is a bottle neck in your application? Anyways, I don't think you can delete a file without creating a File object, unless you are planning on writing your own "native" method which unlinks the file by just taking in the file path as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Why would the code be expensive? Creating temporary objects in Java is not expensive anymore, due to generational GC. And a File is just an object encapsulating a path to the file system. It's not expensive to create one.

Answer (score 0):

Standard java API does not allow this. And thousands of times is almost nothing for modern computer. Creation of `java.io.File` instance takes less time than deletion, so do not worry. If you see any problems with this code you can create cache as a `Map<String, File>` and get the file instance from there.

But again, do not do this unless you see that this is your problem. No pre-mature optimization!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to delete a file in pure Java that doesn't entail creating a `File` object.  The impure alternatives are:

- using JNI or JNA to call native code that will call `unlink` or the Window equivalent,
- running the `rm` or `del` command as an external process.

The first is at best only *marginally* faster than `new File().delete()`.  The second is *significantly* slower.

I'd say that 90+% of the cost of `new File().delete()` is in the system call and the operating system's file system layers.